# Pandas - multiple condition lookup speed

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I'm working with some historical baseball data and trying to get matchup information (batter/pitcher) for previous games.

Example data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'],
        'Year' : ['2017-05-01', '2017-06-03', '2017-08-02', '2018-05-30', '2018-07-23', '2018-09-14', '2017-06-01', '2017-08-03', '2018-05-15', '2018-07-23', '2017-05-01'],
        'ID2' : [1,2,3,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1],
       'Score 2': [1,4,5,7,5,5,6,1,4,5,6],
       'Score 3': [1,4,5,7,5,5,6,1,4,5,6], 
       'Score 4': [1,4,5,7,5,5,6,1,4,5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

lookup_data = {"First_Person" : ['A', 'B'],
             "Second_Person" : ['1', '2'],
             "Year" : ['2018', '2018']}

lookup_df = pd.DataFrame(lookup_data)
```

Lookup df has the current matchups, df has the historical data and current matchups.

I want to find, for example, for Person A against Person 2, what were the results of any of their matchups on any previous date?

I can do this with:

```
history_list = []
def get_history(row, df, hist_list):
    #we filter the df to matchups containing both players before the previous date and sum all events in their history
    history = df[(df['ID'] == row['First_Person']) & (df['ID2'] == row['Second_Person']) & (df['Year'] < row['Year'])].sum().iloc[3:]
    #add to a list to keep track of results
    hist_list.append(list(history.values) + [row['Year']+row['First_Person']+row['Second_Person']])
```

and then execute with apply like so:

```
lookup_df.apply(get_history, df=df, hist_list = history_list, axis=1)
```

Expected results would be something like:

```
1st P  Matchup date 2nd p   Historical scores
A      2018-07-23     2     11 11 11
B      2018-05-15     2     7  7  7
```

But this is pretty slow - the filtering operation takes around 50ms per lookup.

Is there a better way I can approach this problem?  This currently would take over 3 hours to run across 250k historical matchups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge or map and groupby,

```
lookup_df['Second_Person'] =   lookup_df['Second_Person'].astype(int) 

merged = df.merge(lookup_df, left_on = ['ID', 'ID2'], right_on = ['First_Person', 'Second_Person'], how = 'left').query('Year_x < Year_y').drop(['Year_x', 'First_Person', 'Second_Person', 'Year_y'], axis = 1)

merged.groupby('ID', as_index = False).sum()

    ID  ID2 Score 2 Score 3 Score 4
0   A   1   1       1       1
1   B   4   7       7       7
```

Comment: Sorry - I realized I needed to clarify better. I need any previous date before the current date, not just by years. I updated my original post to show this.

Comment: There is a date 0 in your last row of df

Comment: @ctd25, I don't understand how you got 11 for ID A. There is only one row with ID A and ID2 1 which matches with lookup_df

Comment: Ah yeah, I was rushing and mixed it up :) But I was able to test this and it works really nicely!  I just used .query(date_x < date_y).  thank you!